# How to deal with Objective-C errors in dynamic code blocks?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm sure the answer to this question is *embarrassingly* basic, but I'm having trouble understanding how the real-time compiling / error-checking in XCode is supposed to work with the dynamic nature of Objective-C.

For example, I want to setEditing:YES for the tableView of whatever the topViewController is in my stack of view controllers. So I try this:

```
[self.navigationController.topViewController.tableView setEditing: YES animated: YES];
```

And XCode complains: `Property 'tableView' not found on object of type 'UIViewController'`.

Now, this code is in a UIViewController, but it would only be called when the topViewController is a UITableViewController, but obviously Xcode doesn't know that.

How do I fix this? Is this indicative of a bad coding practice on my part? I tried wrapping the line in a conditional to test that topViewController.tableView != nil, but Xcode then just bitches about the conditional line :)

EDIT: Thanks to answers by saadnib and Caleb below, this is what I have now:

```
if ([self.navigationController.topViewController isKindOfClass:([UITableViewController class])] ) {
    UITableViewController *topController = (UITableViewController *)self.navigationController.topViewController;
    [topController.tableView setEditing: YES animated: YES];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you can access the property of topViewController by typecasting it. For example your topViewController name is "FirstViewController" then you can do this as

```
FirstViewController *fvc = (FirstViewController*)self.navigationController.topViewController;

[fvc.tableView setEditing: YES animated: YES];
```

i hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because `self.navigationController.topViewController` returns a pointer of type `UIViewController*`, and UIViewController doesn't have a `tableView` property. @saadnib's answer is correct: if you know that the pointer will always point to a certain UIViewController subclass, you can cast it to that type.

However, even though you "know" that the top view controller will always be a table view controller, you might want to check at run time that that's the case. You could use -isKindOfClass: to see if the controller is a subclass of UITableViewController. You'd still need the cast, of course, but it'd be a little safer.

Comment: Better to use `-respondsToSelector:`

Comment: @JeremyP, I'd normally agree, and I put that in the answer at first but then took it out. If you use -respondsToSelector:, you still need to cast the pointer to some type that has a -tableView method, or to id (I think the compiler doesn't complain if you send any message to id). id seems the wrong direction, since we already know that it's at least a UIViewController, and the OP fully expects that it's a UITableViewController, so we're really asking "is it an instance of class UITableViewController" rather than just "does it respond to -tableView."

Comment: `id` is fine and within the spirit of Objective-C's dynamic typing. `-respondsToSelector:` works even if you add the method to the base class with a category.  On the other hand, if you are going to be using lots of methods defined in a subclass, `-isKindOfClass:` might be better (or create a protocol and use `-conformsToProtocol:`)